# How can I get seed from corrupted world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing some weeks in Minecraft and suddenly my world became corrupted (broken level.dat and level.dat_old).
I heard that it is possible to recreate this world but I dont have any working backups, so what is the way to get world seed?

Maybe there are some info in logs, or it is possible to decompile world seed from broken level.dat?

Comment: That entirely relies on how it is broken. Files don't just break in halves like physical objects, so you need to be more specific what actually happened and what the problem is.

Comment: @FabianRöling level.dat broken

Comment: That's the most unspecific thing you could have possibly answered. I still have zero clue what the problem is.

Comment: @FabianRöling the problem is that I dont have a seed and level.dat file is corrupted, It is not readable

Comment: What does the game do when you open the world?

Comment: @FabianRöling is doesnt see the world. It is not openable in MC, MCedit etc. NBT explorer says that level.dat and level.dat_old are corrupted

Answer (score -1):

type "/seed" then take a screenshot of what the output was, also you can download NBTexplorer and go to your world file and see the seed

Comment: Hi ant, welcome to Arqade! The asker clearly stated that they are unable to get into the world, so using a command while a world is loaded would not work.